# Having trouble understanding memory addressing in assembly

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, memory-address, instructions

I'm looking at a piece of assembly code and I'm stuck trying to make sense of something:

```
incl (%ebx, %eax, 4)
```

What exactly does this do? I tried plugging it into a `.s` file and compiling then watching registers in GDB but when it passes the instruction after I set `ebx` to an address and `eax` to 1 it changed nothing... I'm guessing I don't understand how to use it properly. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't incrementing a register; it is incrementing a memory location computed from the contents of the registers in the the instruction.

Comment: how is it computed?
and what if it was:
incl %ebx, %eax, 4

Comment: That basically means "increment the dword at address `%ebx + %eax * 4`". There's plenty of material explaining this, search for "x86 addressing modes".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not use GAS and AT&T syntax. It is especially invented in order to obfuscate the syntax and to make it unclear and unattractive for the beginners.

This syntax is created to be used by a back-ends for the HLL compilers. Human written programming with it is a masochism.

Even I (with 25 years of assembly programming background) hardly can recognize the normal instruction:

```
    inc dword [ebx+4*eax] 
; increment a double word at memory address (ebx+4*eax)
```

Use [FASM](http://flatassembler.net) instead. It has clear, human-centric syntax, best for hand written assembly programs.

Comment: My computer architecture class strictly revolves around using AT&T/GAS, I'm just trying to work with what I have.  The goal of the class is to teach C but at the same time learn what exactly the compiler is doing to make our code work.  Thanks for the help.